# Open port for Microsoft SQL database connection from outside the Windows7 computer

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, telnet

My Firewall seems to be blocking the connection from anywhere to my local MS Sql Server on my Windows7 development machine.

On Linux and Mysql I could telnet the database ports and it gives response like any other service that is running in some port. On Windows and MS Sql I could not repeat this task.

Also I could connect Mysql from Glassfish server *ping* command and Mysql answers with no problems. The Mysql server could be even on that Windows 7 machine. Again, no way to do this at MS Sql.

I am running out of ideas, what could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box SQL Server is not configured to allow any remote connection. You need to actively allow this so you can connect to it from the network.

I'm assuming you are using 2008, MSDN has an [description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/walzenbach/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008) to enable remote connections that also includes adding Firewall exceptions if this is really the problem.

Comment: +1: This is exactly want I looked for! Thanks @Tex !!

Comment: They even give you a batchfile to set up all the ports.